# Asp.net server interface with a hardware device?

Tags: asp.net, hardware, modem

I've currently developing a web application in asp.net and a smsgateway moderm connected to my server (currently my laptop). is there a way for the asp.net to interface with the moderm that is connected to the server? so i'll be able to send/receive message in a web interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server-side code can interact with the system just like you can with other applications, as long as the application has the proper permissions to do so.